# Exclude chrome/firefox from top command output

Tags: process, firefox, chrome, top

How can I exclude Chrome/Firefox processes from top command output? It's just too messy with them in there, and it isn't important for me to see them there.

Comment: See this Q/A on ServerFault: https://serverfault.com/a/141442

Comment: `killall chrome` and `killall firefox` is one way to make them go away ... ;)

Comment: Lol, messy output to analyze is not good. Killing won't help.

Answer (score 2):

As `top` is a compiled program, you'd need to modify [the source code](http://procps.sourceforge.net/).  Using `ps` it's easily achieved by using:

```
ps aux | grep --invert-match firefox
```

to exclude firefox.

<sub>**Note:** I don't have Chrome, so don't know what the process name is but adding `| grep --invert-match chrome` at the end of the above command should accomplish both *if and only if* Chrome's process name is `chrome` (educated guess)</sub>

Comment: Nice one, how to have the same effect as top with `tree` and only show process of a specific user?

Comment: `tree` is for directories, so I don't get it, so if I were you, I'd [ask a new question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).  **;-)**

Answer (score 2):

The top command is very command-line friendly.  Try launching top like this:

```
top | grep -v firefox
```

Comment: `top | grep -Ev "(firefox|Web|chrome)"` works for me on Kubuntu 18.04 with both Firefox and Google Chrome running. `Web` is for `Web Content` which is what Firefox shows when YouTube is playing.

Comment: @DKBose: Beautiful!, I don't expect that pipe through grep still make `top` monitor other processes.